# Para que serve o módulo __future__?

Tags: python

Já vi em alguns códigos escritos em *Python* a seguinte declaração:

```
 from __future__ import print_function
```

Qual é a finalidade desse módulo `__future__`? Quando é que preciso importar ele para um script que eu estou fazendo?

Por que ele, diferente dos outros módulos, está escrito como se fosse uma propriedade mágica (os underlines antes e depois)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O módulo `__future__` realmente é um pouco mágico. Seria mais preciso ver o `from __future__ import` como uma declaração para o compilador Python ao invés de um `import` típico.

A razão de ser do `from __future__ import` é disponibilizar funcionalidades planejadas para versões futuras do Python mas que não podem ser o comportamento padrão da linguagem ainda para preservar a compatibilidade com programs existentes.

Por exemplo, em Python 2 o `print` é um comando que é chamado sem parênteses:

```
print "Oi Mundo"
```

Já em Python 3, o `print` passou a ser uma função normal, chamada com parênteses

```
print("Oi Mundo")
```

Para facilitar essa transição, a partir do Python 2.6 o print como função é uma funcionalidade opcional. O padrão no Python 2.6 é o print ser um comando mas se você usar `from __future__ import print_function` o print vira uma função.

Para mais informações, veja a [PEP 236](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0236/), que propôs o `__future__`, e a [seção sobre future statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) na documentação oficial.

Comment: @mgibsonbr acho também que ele quis dizer "Sem parênteses"

Comment: ops! s/espaços/parênteses/